# How to setup and use GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

Previously I've asked an question and Micha gave me a helpful advice:[How to find the watershed area for each point in the river network using DEM？](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61152/how-to-find-the-watershed-area-for-each-point-in-the-river-network-using-dem/61157#61157)

After getting the useful DEM file, I began to setup GRASS and use it to solve my problem, I downloaded it from its official site:[Index of /grass64/binary/mswindows/native](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/binary/mswindows/native/), choosing this one:

> WinGRASS-6.4.2-2-Setup.exe

to download.

I have downloaded the main program and two datasets, and then launch GRASS after fininshing installation:

[image]

I create an new folder and put downloaded datasets in it, in my case,

> C:\grassdata

But as I choose this folder as my GIS data directory, the window soon vanished and nothing came up.

I tried many times but the result was just all the same, so I want to setup GRASS correctly, and then use these two useful modules:

- r.watershed elev=DEM thresh= drain=flow_dir_grid
- r.water.outlet drain=flow_dir_grid basin=basin1 easting=X1 northing=Y1

to solve my problem.

How to setup GRASS and could someone provide step by step guidance?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ample information provided on the GRASS website to help you get set-up and started. I would recommend that you review the detailed material [here](http://grass.osgeo.org/documentation/first-time-users/) as well as the [Getting Started Material](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Help#Getting_Started) on the GRASS wiki.

Also, the [GRASS Book](http://www.grassbook.org/) is an excellent reference.

Comment: And see also here: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/helptext.html (or "Help" button in the start menu)