# Getting additional subbasin areas designated by points in river network？

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, grass-gis, arc-hydro

I follow [Watershed and Stream Network Delineation](http://www.crwr.utexas.edu/gis/gishydro07/Introduction/Exercises/Ex4.htm), and here's my workflow：

1. use **Batch Point Generation** to create batch points related to designated points(green dots)
2. **Batch Subwatershed Delineation** using these batch points

and I got this：

[image]

It looks great, but I still can't clip existing subbasins using designated points to get smaller subbasins inside.

Are there tools in **Arc Hydro Tools** or any other tool like **QGIS** or **GRASS** that can help me get my goal？

---

I have got the subbasin area of every river segment using Arc Hydro Tools：

Martin suggested [How to get the subbasin area of each specified river segment？](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82134)

[image]

Now I have some sample stations(the green dots) in the river network, and I'd like to take them as the segment bases, thus I would get more segments, and I want to split the drainage line based on those points and calculate the subbasin area of these new segments：

[image]

I think the key is how to make ArcGIS take these green dots as confluences of rivers as well. And all I want is like this schematic photo：
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: not sure if I understood it completely. But i think you want to use green dots (points) to get sub-basins and then stream reach network for delineated sub-basins with tabular information, is it correct?

Comment: I want to get subbasin areas of every segment including the segment above the green dot.

Answer (score 3):

Ssee http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Creating_watersheds in the Wiki. With [r.water.outlet](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.water.outlet.html) you can calculate a watershed "backwards" from its outlet point.
Furthermore, see also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*

The screenshot shows where to find r.water.outlet in "Processing" (former Sexante) in QGIS 2. Typing into the search field lists name matching commands.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much！I have looked this website you gave me：http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Creating_watersheds, but I used to use GRASS in sextante toolbox under QGIS2.0, I don't know where and how to type those code.

Comment: I edited and added where to find it in QGIS...

Comment: thank you, it seems that I need to put the output of r.watershed module as the input of r.water.outlet, and now I am stuck in this problem：http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84456/problems-using-grass-gui-d-rast-and-r-watershed, could you give me some other advices? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much, with your guide, I successfully used r.water.outlet module, and got some results in this post：http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61152/how-to-find-the-watershed-area-for-each-point-in-the-river-network-using-dem, but the result is still not what I want.